# Checking if any input has been made for each textbox individually

Tags: c#

This is a continuation of my question regarding checking if inputs were made for the textbox for my Visual Studio app. In addition, I need to display several error messages individually if no input was made for specific textboxes (e.g. TextBox 1 and 3 have no input but 2, 4 and 5 have inputs).

```
    private void createDowntimeArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ValuesValid(txtDowntime1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type in Downtime 1.", "Error");
            return; //See ValuesValid() method
        }            
        else if (!ValuesValid(txtDowntime2.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type in Downtime 2.", "Error");
            return; //See ValuesValid() method
        }            
        else if (!ValuesValid(txtDowntime3.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type in Downtime 3.", "Error");
            return; //See ValuesValid() method
        }            
        else if (!ValuesValid(txtDowntime4.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type in Downtime 4.", "Error");
            return; //See ValuesValid() method
        }            
        else if (!ValuesValid(txtDowntime5.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type in Downtime 5.", "Error");
            return; //See ValuesValid() method
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type in valid numbers.", "Error");
        }
        numberInsert[0] = float.Parse(txtDowntime1.Text);
        numberInsert[1] = float.Parse(txtDowntime2.Text);
        numberInsert[2] = float.Parse(txtDowntime3.Text);
        numberInsert[3] = float.Parse(txtDowntime4.Text);
        numberInsert[4] = float.Parse(txtDowntime5.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberInsert.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sum += numberInsert[i]; //Shows sum of floats added up
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Total : " + sum.ToString());
    }
    private bool ValuesValid(string text)
    {
        return float.TryParse(txtDowntime1.Text, out _) &&
            float.TryParse(txtDowntime2.Text, out _) &&
            float.TryParse(txtDowntime3.Text, out _) &&
            float.TryParse(txtDowntime4.Text, out _) &&
            float.TryParse(txtDowntime5.Text, out _);
    } // Discards any text boxes with no input.
```

I onced tried boolean variables to verify if any inputs were made individually but that ended up being scrapped. Any suggestions to get it work with bool variables?